# Why can't pull the dash stream with ffplay?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

The nginx.conf is simple:

```
sudo cat /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf    
worker_processes  1; 
error_log logs/error.log error;
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

rtmp { 
    server { 
        listen 1935; 
        application live { 
            live on; 
            dash on; 
            dash_path /mnt/dash; 
            dash_fragment 15s; 
        } 
    } 
} 
 
http { 
    server { 
        listen 80; 
        location /dash { 
            root /mnt; 
        } 
    }
 
    types {
        text/html html;
        application/dash+xml mpd;
    } 
}
```

I push the web camera to 127.0.0.1.

```
output="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/sample"
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -f flv $output
```

Pull it with rtmp protocol:

```
ffplay  rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/sample
```

Succeeded!

Pull it with dash protocol:

```
ffplay  http://127.0.0.1/dash/sample.mpd
```

It encounter an error:

```
http://127.0.0.1/dash/sample.mpd: Invalid data found when processing input
```

How to fix it?
My os :debian9.

```
ffplay -formats |& grep "DASH Muxer"
  E dash            DASH Muxer
```

Comment: Post output of `ffplay -formats |& grep "DASH Muxer"`

Comment: Your copy of `ffplay` definitely cannot play DASH files, if it could output of the command I suggested would be `DE dash            DASH Muxer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompile `ffplay` with DASH Demuxing enabled. It's
possible that a pre-made package with DASH Demuxing enabled is already
provided for your operating system but since it's not absolutely
certain and you didn't specify what OS you're using I'm going to
describe how to build `ffplay` with DASH Demuxing enabled manually.

Clone ffmpeg repository:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
```

Change to ffmpeg directory:

```
cd ffmpeg
```

Run ./configure script with needed parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/ffmpeg-install --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2
```

Build and install ffplay to `$HOME/ffmpeg-install`:

```
make -j$(nproc) install
```

It took only 4 minutes on my machine. Make sure that the newly built
ffmpeg comes with DASH Demuxing support:

```
$ ~/ffmpeg-install/bin/ffplay -formats |& grep "DASH Muxer"
 DE dash            DASH Muxer
```

Use it instead of the stock ffplay:

```
~/ffmpeg-install/bin/ffplay http://127.0.0.1/dash/sample.mpd
```

References: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853088/3691891)

Comment: Maybe something in the nginx.conf is wrong?

Comment: @scrapy: no, it looks good to me. I can play http://127.0.0.1/dash/sample.mpd after enabling DASH as I described.

Comment: My output is  E dash            DASH Muxer ,yours are   DE dash            DASH Muxer,so i have to compile the ffplay for DASH?

Comment: @scrapy: yes, I thought it's clear enough. See the reference answer I linked to.

Comment: Something missing in your configuration command, no ffplay after compiling.

Comment: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/ffmpeg-install --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2

Comment: Nothing is missing. You need to run `make` to compile.